# Python Code for n Choose k - How does it work?

Tags: python, math, permutation

I came across this code:

https://diego.assencio.com/?index=50ed9dcd9009dd70c3a2f8822271e4c7

```
def bitmasks(n,m):
    if m < n:
        if m > 0:
            for x in bitmasks(n-1,m-1):
                yield (1 << (n-1)) + x
            for x in bitmasks(n-1,m):
                yield x
        else:
            yield 0
    else:
        yield (1 << n) - 1
 
# print each value as a 4 bit binary number
for b in bitmasks(4,2):
    print('{:04b}'.format(b))
```

A bit clearer version:

```
def bitmasks(n, m):
    if n == m:
        yield (1 << n) - 1
    elif m > 0:
        for x in bitmasks(n-1, m-1):
            yield (1 << (n-1)) + x
        for x in bitmasks(n-1, m):
            yield x
    else:
        yield 0
```

This generates all the permutations of `n choose k` using bit masks. Could someone explain to me how it works? I am finding it hard to intuitively grasp what is going on.

I understand that (1 << (n - 1)) + x is adding 2^(n - 1) to x, but how does that generate all the right permutations?

Edit:

My understanding is as follows:

For `n choose k`, we need to generate a sequence of `k 1's` from `n` positions. Each of the n positions can be either `1 or 0`.

To do this, this code uses some sort of recursive magic:

1. The code will recurse all the way down until it hits `m == n`, or the following branch:

```
else:
  yield (1 << n) - 1
```

By definition, this will set the rightmost `k` bits to `1`.

2. Now, using this as the starting point, we go up the recursive tree. Here is where I am bit lost:

First, the first for loop. We add `(1 << (n - 1))` to the numbers, `x` stored in our iterator. This will set the `(n - 1)th` bit to 1?

I am not really sure how the two for loops construct the result.

Comment: By the way,
```for x in bitmasks(n-1, m):
    yield x```
Can be replaced with `yield from bitmasks(n-1, m)`

Comment: @Jonathan1609 I doubt this helps OP one bit (pun intended...)

Comment: Can you explain what all you *do* understand?

Comment: @DeepSpace i said that by the way, not related to his issue.

Comment: I added my limited understanding @ScottHunter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm works recursively, so to explain how it works I will rely on the "leap of faith" - we should assume the recursive calls do the correct thing, [and from that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) we want to deduce that the function overall does the correct thing.

The base cases solved without recursive calls are straightforward:

- If `m == n` there is only one combination, which consists of `n` 1 bits in a row. This is equal to `(1 << n) - 1`; if you aren't sure why, it's a good exercise for you to try to figure out for yourself.
- If `m == 0` there is likewise only one combination, which consists of no 1 bits. This is equal to `0`.

For the recursive case, we have `n` positions which we want to fit `m` 1 bits into. The set of all combinations can be partitioned into two subsets:

- The combinations where the `n`th bit is a 1. We can generate all the combinations like this by recursively finding the combinations where there are `m - 1` 1 bits in the remaining `n - 1` positions, and adding a 1 bit to the `n`th position. We get a 1 bit into the nth position with the expression `1 << (n - 1)`, where the shift is by `n - 1` instead of `n` because we start counting from 0.
- The combinations where the `n`th bit is a 0. This means the remaining `n - 1` positions must have all `m` of the 1 bits, which are found by the recursive call.

Comment: Thanks @kaya3,

For the first recursive case, how do we ensure `"We can generate all the combinations like this by recursively finding the combinations where there are m - 1 1 bits in the remaining n - 1 positions"`?

From what I understand the base case of `n==m` only produces `n` 1 bits in a row, but there are permutations such as `1001`

Comment: You simply assume that the recursive call `bitmasks(n-1, m-1)` generates them correctly. Permutations like `1001` (i.e. `n = 4, m = 2`) are not handled by the base cases.

Comment: Thanks, so those cases `1001` are generated by the series of recursive calls